# Suggest Event pattern design in database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Can anyone suggest a good event pattern design or framework for changes in table in oracle.

Changes are not just the based on the column value change,but also the business driven logic .All the logging should be driven by some event setup.

At the end we track the changes and drive the business logic based on the changes .

I might be talking too high level,sorry for that  :)

Comment: Can you please expand your question?  What do you have in mind when you say that changes are also based on "business driven logic"?  Logging DML outcomes is easy but the other bit might be trickier.

Comment: Are you saying that this is two step procedure: 1. record changes taking place in the database 2. feed recorded changes to "business logic" ? How the "business logic" is implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume TableA needs to be tracked for ColumnA.

1. Create AUDIT_TRAIL Table with columns TABLENAME, COLUMNNAME, OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE, DATEANDTIME, PK_SEQ
2. Create a Trigger to poll TableA for any change in ColumnA, and insert them into AUDIT_TRAIL (PK_SEQ should be a Oracle Sequence Number, DATEANDTIME should be from sysdate)

Something like this for trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_table_audit
before insert or update or delete on tableA REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row
begin
if inserting or deleting then
insert into audittrail (....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the fine manual: [Using Triggers to Write Audit Data to a Separate Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#BCGEADJF):

> You can use triggers to supplement the built-in auditing features of Oracle Database. The trigger that you create records user actions to a separate database table. When an activity fires the trigger, the trigger records the action in this table. Triggers are useful when you want to record customized information such as before-and-after changes to a table.

Reading even more the fine manual: [PL/SQL Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm):

> A trigger is like a stored procedure that Oracle Database invokes automatically whenever a specified event occurs.

On top of that you can build a setup engine that turns triggers on and off. The "business logic" can later read the data recorded by the triggers.

I assume you're not interested in auditing. For the details see e.g. [Verifying Security Access with Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm).

Answer (score 0):

How about you start with using [TRIGGERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm)? And then from there, you could call procedures/functions from a package body for tracking the changes on the table/s.